# Telegram Bot InlineKeyboardButton, How to know which dynamically button is pressed?

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I'm using [Python Telegram Bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) and I'm struggling with handling callback query handlers.

## The problem

I've created a list of inlinekeyboard buttons (see image below), and they all trigger the same callback query. However, I'm unable to extract which inline keyboard button has been pressed and triggered the callback query.

### How it looks in Telegram

[image: inlinekeyboard_in_telegram]

## Background info

In my code I've created this inline keyboard which grows depending on the number of items in the List 'drawdates' (see the def below).

```
def drawdate_keyboard(drawdates):
    keyboard = []

    for idx, drawdate in enumerate(drawdates):
         keyboard.append([InlineKeyboardButton(drawdate, callback_data=str(SET_DRAWDATE))])
  
    keyboard.append([InlineKeyboardButton('Cancel', callback_data=str(CANCEL))])

    return InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
```

I'm using a conversation handlers which looks like this:

```
conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler("start", start)],
        states={
                CALLBACKS_ROUTES: [
                    CallbackQueryHandler(add_ticket, pattern=str(ADD_TICKET)),
                    CallbackQueryHandler(get_drawdates, pattern=str(GET_DRAWDATES)),
                    CallbackQueryHandler(check_tickets, pattern="^" + str(CHECK_TICKETS) + "$"),
                    CallbackQueryHandler(clear_tickets, pattern="^" + str(CLEAR_TICKETS) + "$"),
                ],
                TICKET: [
                    MessageHandler(Filters.text & ~Filters.command, ticket),
                    CallbackQueryHandler(start_over, pattern="^" + str(CANCEL) + "$"),
                ],
                DRAWDATE: [
                    CallbackQueryHandler(set_drawdate, pattern=str(SET_DRAWDATE)),
                    CallbackQueryHandler(start_over, pattern="^" + str(CANCEL) + "$"),
                ],
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler("start", start)],
        #per_message=True,
    )
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(conv_handler)
```

and the callback is catched by this:

```
def set_drawdate(update: Update, context) -> int:
    query = update.callback_query  
    query.answer()
```

Comment: You can't include the date in `callback_data`?

Answer (score 1):

As Ouroborus already implied, the `callback_data` parameter is there to allow you to identify the button. You should make sure that each button has a unique `callback_data` which identifies the button.

Since you're using the `python-telegram-bot` library, let me also point out that this library includes convenience functionality that allows you to pass arbitrary objects as `callback_data`. In your case, you could e.g. pass `datetime.datetime` objects. See [here](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/v13.x-wiki/wiki/Arbitrary-callback_data) for more info.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I've got another look at the example and got arbitrarycallbackdatabot.py working. I've tweaked the build_keyboard to add a [InlineKeyboardButton("Clear",callback_data="Clear")]) to the InlineKeyboard.

However, I'm now stuck at the handler, since the example doesn't use a pattern.
I've added the following handler:

updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(clear, pattern="Clear"))

What should I do with this handler to still react to the buttons to numbers?
 
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(list_button))

Comment: I recommend to carefully read the docs of the `pattern` argument of `CallbackQueryHandler` :)